# How to inject / intercept DbConnection instances for an existing db provider?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, ef-core-2.2

Let's suppose I have an ASP.NET Core app with a controller that uses a `DbContext` instance as a constructor parameter, following standard dependency injection conventions.

Both the controller and the `DbContext` types are database-agnostic. The app sets the default options to be used by every DI `DbContext` instances in its `StartUp` class. At one point on runtime, EF Core will instantiate an instance of `SqlConnection` whenever it judges necessary.

I'm interested in how this connection instance is created. More specifically, I would like to attach event handlers on `InfoMessage` and `StateChange`. This, however, must be done in a way that won't break EF Core's normal behavior and management of connections.

Is there any service I can inject (IoC) so that EF uses an `SqlConnection` instance factory of my own? Or is there *at least* a way I can intercept the instance it creates?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what kind of connection is there between `SqlConenction` and handles for entities (I assume `InfoMessage` is your entity)

Comment: @Tseng https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.2

Comment: `(SqlConnection)DbContext.Database.Connection`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.connection?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: @JessedeWit this is EF6, unfortunately. I'm looking for a EFCore solution.

Comment: Those are the entity framework 6.2.0 docs, but I guess that doesn't help you very much...

Comment: Sadly, no. AFAIK the Core version dynamically creates a DbConnection instance when one is needed, rather than permanently set one on a DbContext.

Comment: Here's a completely undocumented method you can try: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getdbconnection

Comment: @JessedeWit won't this just punctually return an adhoc instance of a connection object out of a given DbContext?

Comment: Not sure but assume EF Core creates new instance of `SqlConnection` every time it need to execute a query.

Comment: @Fabio this is also what I think. It has to use a factory class at some point for this, though. If this class can be injected then it would solve my issue. There are so. Many. Things. Injected in EF Core through IoC, its hard to believe connection instances wouldnt be one of thesr...

Comment: DbContext accepts `DbContextOptions` instance as a constructor argument. Those options contains all required information to create a connection. Options can be created by `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and builder has method `UseLoggerFactory` which takes `ILoggerFactory` abstractions as an argument. So you need to implement your own `ILoggerFactory` to log information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, from the [ef core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-2.1): 
(Edited after first comment)

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = GetSqlConnection();
        services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this breaks the requirement that DbContext types must be db agnostic. The same context object needs to be able to work with a completely different db provider. It's okay for the app to know which db server shall be used, but contexts are defined in a reusable fashion, in an external project. What I am really looking for here is a IoC approach. Perhaps there isn't any at all... :-\ I still very much appreciate the effort, though. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but this raises quite a few questions (hating me yet? :) ). With this pattern, who's in charge of disposing of the connection instance when it is no longer needed? What happens when multiple threads attempts to open / close that unique instance? What if I have other DbContext classes, should they share that unique instance too?

Comment: Here, this may clue you in on what I'm looking for: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1206764/Clean-Factory-Design-Pattern-with-IoC-Container

Comment: Again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No, you have a valid point. You want te be able to manage the connection lifecycle. And I don't know actually. Hoping someone else will answer your question.

Comment: So I dug into EF Core's source code and AFAICT the only way to inject my own connection instance is indeed to create it and pass it to the db context options builder as a singleton which  will outlive the context. There doesn't seem to be an IoC service for this. So that makes this answer the right one. Again, thank you very much.